# JupyterHub vscode extension Error: Unable to determine base url of Jupyter Hub Server

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyterhub

I want to access jupyterHub from my vscode. I have my URL like this: `https://<my-hub-url>/user/<my-hub-user-name>/?token=<my-token>.`

This URL works just fine in Chrome if I click on it and the connection between VSCode & the hub is also working using other computer but on mine computer I got :

[image]

Here are the JupyterHub enxtension logs :

```
Error: Unable to determine base url of Jupyter Hub Server
    > at getJupyterHubBaseUrl (c:\Users\aa\.vscode\extensions\ms-toolsai.jupyter-hub-2023.10.1003012305\dist\extension.node.js:64314:9)
```

VSCODE version : Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
Date: 2023-11-09T10:51:52.184Z
Electron: 25.9.2
ElectronBuildId: 24603566
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

JupyterHub extension version : v2023.10.1003012305

I have miniconda installed & Git.

What do I need to to to make it works on my computer ?

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue and would appreciate any help as well...